# Composition series of general linear group $GL(2,7)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to get the composition factors of $GL(2,7)$, where $GL(2,7)$ means general linear group of degree $2$ over field $\mathbb{Z_7}$.

Note that in a composition series of a group $G$, such that $$G=G_0 \triangleright G_1 \triangleright G_2 \triangleright \cdots \triangleright G_n = 1$$ for any $i$, $G_i \diagup G_{i+1}$ is simple.

My work done so far is $$GL(2,7) \triangleright G_1 \triangleright SL(2,7) \triangleright Z(SL(2,7)) \triangleright 1$$

I need to find this $G_1$ such that $GL(2,7) \diagup G_1$ and $G_1 \diagup SL(2,7)$ are both simple. (By theorem, $SL(2,7) \diagup Z(SL(2,7))$ is simple)

Please tell me the steps how you get this $G_1$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ is the kernel of the determinant homomorphism $\textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_7) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_7^{\ast}$.  So you just need to find a composition series for $\mathbb{F}_7^{\ast}$ and pull it back.  The group $\mathbb{F}_7^{\ast}$ is cyclic with six elements, so you can take its subgroup $\{1, -1\}$.  The quotient will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Spoiler:

> Pulling this back, you get the subgroup $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_7) \subseteq H \subseteq \textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ of matrices with determinant $\pm 1$.